# Vote to Reopen an Optical Drive Question

Tags: discussion, reopen-request

[My Question](https://superuser.com/q/1564879/1097820) I was wondering if this question can be voted to be reopened. I would like to hear any objections, with the reasoning of course. Since the tag requires reasoning. My reasoning is that the question has been added plenty of details. Any other details could be asked.

Comment: If you took some time to improve the formatting of your question.  You might have some users vote to reopen your question.  What software are you using to try to write the optical disk?  Instead of replying with a comment, you should edit and improve the question, replying with a comment won't result in anyone voting to reopen your question.

Comment: I was asking what software are you using to create the disk.  Windows has built-in support but not everyone uses it.  My request for more information is reasonable.  You suggesting I have no sense is extremely rude.  Your asking the community to vote to reopen your question. Your response to clarify your question and improve the format of your question is very reasonable.  I won’t vote to reopen your question until your question has the required information to answer your question.  I will be honest, I have no idea what you mean by, “the sense becomes one with you.” other than as an insult

Comment: @Ramhound No, my apologies I thought you were asking what files types I was trying to burn into the compact disk because it is not accepting anything. Other than that you are right, and I will verify that that clarification helps.

Answer (score 1):

> would like to hear any objections, with the reasoning of course.

Your question lacks a great deal of formatting which makes it very difficult to read.  You have intentionally or unintentionally bolded specific words unnecessarily.    Bolding should be used sparingly.

If you disregard the fact your formatting needs to be improved, it's not clear what you are using to burn the data to the disk, and at what stage the writing fails at.  Since you are clearly running Windows, if you were using the built-in functionality, there would be two stages.  The first stage is preparing the disk session, this involves selecting if you want to keep the session or close it after the data is written.  Understanding what you have selected would help tremendously. The second stage would be after you have selected the option to finialize the disk.

You have also not selected what type of disk you are using.  Your drive only supports specific optical disks based on my research.  You must understand it supports more than a  half dozen different types of optical disks, and you wouldn't be the first person, to refer to an optical disk as a "CD-ROM disk".  So understanding what type of disk you are using would help tremendously.

I might actually be overthinking your problem, if you cannot even access your disk to initialize the session, that would change the premise of your question entirely.  **It would, of course, raise the question if the drive ever worked in the device.**  It would also be helpful to know if the device is properly recognized in Device Manager.

> Any other details could be asked.

Some of the details I am pointing out, specifically the type of disk you are using, shouldn't be things we have to ask for you to provide.  Even if we do have to ask for them, you have used incredibly vague words like "CD", believe it or not, "CD" isn't a very good description.

You don't actually specify in any great detail the reason the existing question doesn't answer your question.  **You really only indicate it did not resolve your problem but offered no details.**  Your question could easily be improved so it could be reopened.

Comment: My apologies for yesterday it's just I have come across many insensitive remarks when it comes from users. I am honestly trying to learn and troubleshoot much myself, I am at the beginner's level when it comes to this. I appreciate your help and time.